# Open URL without Webbrowser or Inet control vb6

Tags: web, url, browser, vb6, msinet

Is there a way to open a URL in VB6 application without using Webbrowser or MSInet components?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. VB6 does not have any intrinsic means of displaying a web page in an application. You have to use a third party control. On the other hand, this shouldn't be a problem, because you are essentially using a component of Microsoft Internet Explorer. In fact, you should *not* be distributing this control, because you would likely damage the end user's Windows installation.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to open the URL in a browser window, then use ShellExecute: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute _
                            Lib "shell32.dll" _
                            Alias "ShellExecuteA"( _
                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                            ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                            ByVal lpFile As String, _
                            ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                            ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                            ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
                            As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim r As Long
   r = ShellExecute(0, "open", "http://www.microsoft.com", 0, 0, 1)
End Sub
```

This will open the URL in the default browser.

Otherwise, if you need to display the webpage inside your app, use the WebBrowser control.

Comment: thansks, as I stated in question I want to open a web page in VB6 application and without using WebBrowser, as it would require me to redistribute this .ocx with my executable which I'm currently forbidden to do.(project management stuff)

Comment: I don't think that OCX(for WebBrowser control) needs to be distributed along with your app. PC with IE installed would have that OCX, I believe. My VB is a bit rusty. So, do a test run. What kind of operation are you doing with the app? If you don't like the classic Package&Deployment of VB, then you could make use of the free Inno Setup compiler to create the setup file for your app.

Comment: It needs the OCX to be distributed. Unfortunately I am allowed to place only single file (be it .exe or other) as my application on a virtual server where it's going to be used.

Comment: The control does need the OCX to be redistributed but `ShellExecute()` does not need the control. It just needs some web browser installed on the computer. The "single file" is a pretty arbitrary and stupid restriction though, epsecially as any VB6 apps need at least 5 other runtime DLLs to be installed.

Comment: @Deanna it is something to be used for penetration testing, and is very much reasonable restriction. I don't want to go into details, but that's just how it is.

Comment: @Deanna and I need the web page to be displayed inside the VB6 application, not in a web browser as I already mentioned twice.

Comment: @Deanna oh and all the dll-s VB6 app needs to execute are already bundled with windows unless you use other controls from within VB6 like WebBrowser.

Comment: @astralmaster Only since Vista. All previous versions may have had them by luck but there is no guarantee.

Comment: @ I have them on MS WinXP SP2 and MS Server 2003 R2.

Comment: @astralmaster You may well do. Doesn't mean they are part of the OS.

Comment: @Deanna Actually I meant they are part of the OS. Even Windows 98 contains VB runtime libraries just of older version (not MSVBVM6) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx

Comment: @astralmaster So did I. Nothing in that article says the (the VB6 runtimes) are explicitly preinstalled on pre Vista. It was used by some optional components of XP so it may well have been included, but is far form guaranteed. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/11/7065021.aspx) for the same situation with MFC.

Comment: @Deanna It does but 'between the lines'.  very well, read here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314720   and here:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823746   Notice that these versions of windows do NOT even have service packs installed.  and Finally read here:  http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=125561